# Walk through VS Cut through

Tags: word-usage, usage

> Can I cut through here?
>
> Can I walk through here?

And:

> He cuts through my yard everyday.
>
> He walks through my yard everyday.

Are "walk through" and "cut through" equally likely in this context? I mean I've read both of them being used in this context, so what sounds better?

Comment: You could walk through a yard for any reason, but _cut through_ implies 'taking a short cut' to avoid having to walk round the outside.

Comment: Yes. 'Walk though' is a simple description of the action, and 'cut through' suggests knowledge of, or speculation about, the walker's intention or purpose. he walks through my yard, he cuts through my yard to get to the main road.